# how to apply h2 span css in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to apply custom h2 span css in material ui, for that I have used this code but I am getting error what I want to do I want to apply class for `h2` then its inner class `h2 span`. How can I apply this css for it with material ui? Can anyone please help me?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    h2 : {
            width: '100%', 
            textAlign: 'center', 
            borderBottom: '1px solid #000', 
            lineHeight: '0.1em',
            margin: '10px 0 20px', 
        }, 
        h2 span: { 
             background:'#fff', 
             padding:'0 10px', 
        }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

to style elements using nested style, following is the way

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    h2: {
        width: "100%",
        textAlign: "center",
        borderBottom: "1px solid #000",
        lineHeight: "0.1em",
        margin: "10px 0 20px",
        "& span": {
            background: "#fff",
            padding: "0 10px"
        }
    }
}));
```

now to style the `h2` give the `className= {classes.h2}` to the element